2d character distorting when animating
I intend to animate a 2D character. The moment I press my space bar the character gets distorted.

I still went on to try and move the arm anyway (just to see) and the arms and head seem locked in their distorted position. I have tried reseting origins for the parts I wanna move as suggested by Youtube videos but it's not working.


Regarding to your other question you know that you have 3 Empties that control the head, and the left and right hands.
The yellow hand and head bones have IK constraints with the Empty objects as targets. You can check this in Pose mode.
The constraints lock the bones and makes them point to the targets. If you now look where the Empty objects are then it's clear why your character looks distorted.

Note that Auto Keying (7) is active! There are a lot of keyframe. I'm not sure if this is indented. Auto Keying will automatically create keyframes for the selected frame when you change the Location, Rotation or Scale of the objects. The input fields will turn yellow to indicate that.

The solution for the distortion is simply: just move the Empty objects.
Your armature has keyframes that you probabably don't want. Especially the Scale value should be reset to (1.0, 1.0, 1.0). Remove the keyframes, and apply the Scale (Ctrl+A in Object mode).

Thank you very much, here goes my night making all these adjustments, i'll be back with  feedback after. one more question though, which option do you think will be easier? between  correcting errors in this character or to start afresh, making another character, then append that one to my scene?

I would keep this character. It's just the scale of the armature you should apply because it can cause more problems in future, and remove the unnecessary keyframes. These keyframes can cause confusion because if you change things that are keyframed and you save & reopen the blend file, the state is reset to the keyframe. So changes can "disappear" (reset). But overall, it's not that the character is completely broken.

thanks, I did as you advised and I'm making progress... final question (I'm sorry) but is it possible to have the cloth effect on my 2D character for his T shirt?
